# Python Binary Search Trees - Error in checking keys where 8 is greater than all

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write some functions for binary search trees, and the ones I have seem to run fine for all cases except one. Whenever I send the value 9 as a key it assumes 8 is greater than every number.

Here is my insert code:

```
def insert( node, key): 

    # If the tree is empty, return a new node 
    if node is None: 
        return Node(key) 

    # Otherwise recur down the tree 
    if key < node.key: 
        node.left = insert(node.left, key) 
    else:
        node.right = insert(node.right, key) 

    # return the (unchanged) node pointer 
    return node
```

Along with this, here is the code for inorder traversal:

```
def InOrder(x):
    """In-Order Traversal of a BST"""
    if x != None:
        InOrder(x.left)
        print(x.key, end = " ")
        InOrder(x.right)
```

If I test this out by giving the values 30, 15, 8, 10, the order of my inorder traversal comes out as:

```
10 15 30 8
```

I'm not sure why it thinks 8 is larger than the rest of the items though.

I tested a few numbers less than 10, and this seems to happen to all of them.

Comment: I tried this exact code and cannot reproduce. Are you sure 8 is an integer and not string?

Comment: Just as @Marat said, I run the exact code and it is printing properly. Maybe the problem is some other part of the code but simply writing a node class and using the same code as you work perfectly fine. Also, the way you insert and do inorder traversal is correct as well. As I said it might because of some other part of your code. Maybe share your whole code ?

Comment: Have you traced what your tree will look like after each insertion?  This would be a great time to use a debugger.  hold a reference to the root node, and try printing the tree (from the root) after each insertion.  I would expect, executing with pen and paper, that the in-order traversal produces `8 10 15 30` as expected.

Comment: How are you calling insert?

Comment: Is `if node is None:` the base case for `insert`? Implying that at some point `node.left` or `node.right` is None? I'm have a hard time finding a path to the last `return node` statement in `insert`. Maybe you should include a [mcve] of `Node` and your tree?

Answer (score 4):

Python will allow you to use this code to sort numbers and to sort strings.  If you use it to sort strings, it will compare character by character.  You appear to be sorting the strings "10", "15", "30", "8".

```
>>> 8 < 12
True
>>> "8" < "12"
False
>>> "Bilbo" < "Frodo"
True
```

To fix this, you probably want to change where you originally call `insert` f.  For example, instead of `insert(mystringvalue, head)`, use `insert(int(mystringvalue), head)`.

Comment: This shows how valuable it is to have *complete*, reproducible code in a question.  Good catch!